# NoMethodError (undefined method `before_validation' for xxx:Class)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

1. I am getting 'after_validation' error when the the code visit ib/better_date_picker/model.rb:21
2. Earlier with Ruby 2.3.4 and rails 5.0, the same code was working.
3. When I upgraded the version of ruby to 2.5.3 and rails to 5.2.3, I start getting this error of after_validation.

Comment: The error is being caused in better_date_picker gem

Comment: I think you need to mention your gem specification in question instead of comment

Comment: please post code snippet too which will help to give answer

Comment: This method is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version. The last existing version is (v2.3.8). You can use other callbacks method to overcome this issue.